# what is the #! sign in the url what does it mean?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is it when a link has a pound “#” sign in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800187/what-is-it-when-a-link-has-a-pound-sign-in-it)

i saw the #! sign in the url 
like :

```
http://www.google.jo/#!
```

but i dont know what is it mean?
i know that 
this

```
http://www.foo.com#bar
```

is used to link an element in the page .
but what about ! character

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called a URL HASH and is used for in-page bookmarking. It is now also used to maintain page state in AJAX applications. Anything after the # can easily be parsed and re-written without forcing a page reload, allowing the JavaScript code to load/hide/show page elements based on the developer's choosing.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a hash, and it is used to denote an anchor in the page. Basically when the page loads it will seek out the anchor and scroll the page to it.

http://www.google.jo/#hl=ar&source=hp

```
<div>content</div>
<div id="hl-ar">scroll here</div>
<div>content</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, the `#` was used in URLs to tell the browser to jump to an anchor in the page with the name following the `#`.

In modern AJAX applications, it allows modification of the location bar URL without the page needing to reload, allowing the Back button on the browser to move back through AJAX state, as well as bookmarking of AJAX pages.

Answer (score 1):

`#` in the url acts like a `goto statement`. ie move to a particular section of the same page.

Besides that it is also used by applications that heavily use ajax to render the larger part  of the website without refreshing the page (ie the page doesn't refresh but a considerable amount of html is requested from the server using ajax giving an impression that an entire page is loaded).

These apps face a problem that when the users click on the back or refresh button in the browser, it may not show them the correct page because there is no refresh happening. So a work around is applied by appending the history information to the url separated by `#`. And when the user clicks on refresh or back button, this information is used to take them to the correct page. There is a jquery plugin available that does this.

Also recently I came across [this](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) doc from google that explains how to make ajax applications 'crawlable' by using `#!` in the url

Answer (score 0):

`(#)` is a hash sign.

It's used to indicate named parts of a page which allow the website to link to not just a page, but a particular part of it.