# Extra code add at end of the url in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the Wordpress CMS to make a site but I face a problem with Wordpress' url create.

When I click on page link, the page url looks like this:

```
http://example.com/page/?ID=603#
```

After some time the page url looks like this:

```
http://example.com/page/?ID=603#.USY_Xx1HI1M
```

I can't understand how to add this code `.USY_Xx1HI1M` at the end of the url.

So guys, if you have any solution for this problem, please share with me.

Comment: First off, in case you are not sure what the `#` symbol does see [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800187/what-is-it-when-a-link-has-a-pound-sign-in-it) and [HTML Links ID](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Comment: WordPress does not do that by default. A plugin or something in your theme is doing it. And what is the _problem_? Is anything actually broken by this?

Comment: I got the solution for this this code add cause of the i use add this plugin in my wordpress website.This will add a short hashtag to the end of your URLs. This lets us reveal how often visitors copy your URL from their address bar to share.

Answer (score 0):

There is a two ways to remove the hash tag from the URL.

1) In the script, there is a property which control to display hashtag or not. Just set 'hashAddressBar: false'

2) When generating a code for the button there is a radio button saying 'Track when users share by copying your URL' so just uncheck this and it wont generate hast tag for URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you used addthis, double check that you have set `data_track_clickback` and `data_track_addressbar` to false, you can read more here: https://www.addthis.com/academy/removing-hashtags-anchors-and-tracking-codes-from-your-urls/