# Showing an image using JavaScript/jQuery - Best practice approach?

Tags: jquery, jscript

I've got a simple function that can either return a match found or no match found result.

If no match is found I want it to display a generic "no user found" image. The below code works fine, but I want to do this the right way. This link

[Show/hide image with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318357/show-hide-image-with-javascript)

seems to discuss a far more complex way of achieving what I'm doing.

But is my method incorrect?

JS

```
success: function (friendMatches) {
            if (friendMatches.length === 0)
                console.log('NO MATCH FOUND!!!');
        $(".no_user").show();
            else // Query executed with success
                console.log('MATCH FOUND!!!');
        },
```

HTML

```
<img style="display:none" src="/img/no-user.png" class ="no_user" alt="No user found">
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, other than it's confusing to read without { } around your `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

JS:

```
success: function (friendMatches) {
            var src;
            if (friendMatches.length === 0) {
                src = 'no-user';
                alt = 'No user found';
            } else { // Query executed with success
                src = userFilename; //Put in the correct filename
                alt = userName; // Put in the correct username
            }
                $(".userImage").attr('src', '/img/' + src '.png');
                $(".userImage").attr('alt', alt);
        },
```

HTML:

```
<img class="userImage" src="" alt="" />
```

This way, you don't need an unused object in the dom.