# String getting split on '#' when passing to a RESTful Web Service in Java through GET method

Tags: java, web-services, rest, get, jersey

I am having a RESTful Java Web Service that accepts a long string with '#' in between.

When I am trying to send the string to the method while calling, the string is getting split on '#' and I can retrieve the [0] value alone.

Before sending the message is intact, but after using this..

```
req.open("GET","https://localhost:8443/registername/resources/registerName/"+"My#Name", true);
req.send();
```

is the problem.

These are the first few lines in the Web Service...

```
@GET
@Path("/{message}")
public String validateName(@PathParam("message") String message) throws Exception{
    System.out.println(message);
...}
```

And, it displays "My" alone.

Can anyone please help me on why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In URLs, a # sign indicates a "named anchor," something that local javascript, and it is not sent to the remote server, so when you have the URL:

```
https://localhost:8443/registername/resources/registerName/My#Name
```

Name isn't sent to the server. You need to use a different split character.

See [What is it when a link has a pound "#" sign in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800187/what-is-it-when-a-link-has-a-pound-sign-in-it) or http://www.hypergurl.com/anchors.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP post or get will not read anything after #,
Do a URLEncode before doing POST or GET.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the part after the # is sent up with the GET request.