# Invoke <a /> tag programmatically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have these tags

```
<li><a href="#view2" >Photo</a></li>
<li><a href="#view3">Data</a></li>
<li><a href="#view4">Cloud Shop</a></li>
<li><a href="#view5">Upload</a></li>
<li><a href="#view6">Site Check</a></li>
<li><a href="#view7">Others</a></li>
```

I want to invoke them from code behind using c#. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Define "invoke", especially in this context.

Comment: If by 'invoke' you mean access their details then you can add a runat=server tag and an ID to each one. Then just call the ID in the codebehind and add / edit details there. NOTE: This won't give you the same level of control as a asp:hyperlink

Comment: By "invoke" what I mean is I want to call the click events of these anchor tags using c#.

Comment: You can't. A ["pound sign href", "fragment" or "named anchor"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800187/what-is-it-when-a-link-has-a-pound-sign-in-it) usually just causes the _browser_ to scroll to the named element, unless there's some JavaScript attached that handles the click event. The JavaScript code runs _after_ your C# code. Explain what the serverside C# code should do with these links and when.

Comment: Use `LinkButton`, you can call `Click` on them.

Comment: are you fine with jquery??

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you access to the  tags:

```
<li><a ID="lnk1" runat="server" href="#view2" >Photo</a></li>
<li><a ID="lnk2" runat="server" href="#view3">Data</a></li>
<li><a ID="lnk3" runat="server" href="#view4">Cloud Shop</a></li>
<li><a ID="lnk4" runat="server" href="#view5">Upload</a></li>
<li><a ID="lnk5" runat="server" href="#view6">Site Check</a></li>
<li><a ID="lnk6" runat="server" href="#view7">Others</a></li>
```

Then in code behind you can do something like:

```
lnk4.Attributes.Add("class","active");
```

To give the link a css class of active.

UPDATE: I see you want access to the click events, I'd recommend using a LinkButton instead, easier to work with.