# Java - new URL(...) doesn't escape the first character

Tags: java, url, github, url-parameters

I am trying to create a link that opens the `New issue` page on Github filling it with existing knowledge of the problem.

In order to do so, i am using the query parameters like followed:

```
https://github.com/User/Repository/issues/new?title=Some text&body=More Text
```

That works fine, however i am trying to format the document using Markdown and all symbols are being escaped after creating a new `URL` by calling

```
URL url = new URL("https://github.com/User/Repository/issues/new?title=Some text&body=# Header # Another header");
```

The result will be this:

```
https://github.com/User/Repository/issues/new?title=Some text&body=# Header %23 Another header
```

the second `#` is being escaped, but the first isn't and i don't quite understand why.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suspect that is because many urls use one # for params that are evaluated in JavaScript .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the URL parser is treating your first `#` as a fragment (a.k.a. [anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800187/what-is-it-when-a-link-has-a-pound-sign-in-it), e.g. `<a name="named-anchor">`). Since according to [RFC-3986: Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3), the fragment must come last and `#` is a reserved character, anything after that first `#` is assumed to be part of that fragment, causing the parser to encode any further "invalid" characters, such as your second `#`. From the RFC:

> The generic URI syntax consists of a hierarchical sequence of components referred to as the scheme, authority, path, query, and fragment.
>
> `URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]`

Note that `fragment` comes last, and is delimited by the `#`.

The best way to handle this would be to:

1. [encode the `body` query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330104/encoding-url-query-parameters-in-java) on your own or
2. use an HTTP client that does the escaping for you, e.g. [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) from Spring or [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/).

Comment: the problem is, that i dont do the http request myself, but use `Desktop.browse` instead, since i want the browser to open up.

Comment: Then you want (1). Where you're creating your URL to pass in to `Desktop.browse`, use the answers from the link in my answer to encode your query parameters when creating it.