# How to prevent strings getting cut at the # sign?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I'm creating a social network and I wanna include the #hashtag feature...problem is posts are cut at the #. For example, if I wrote, "Hello #StackOverflow community!", the resulting string would be "Hello ". Below are the code and a debug screenshot.

```
$("#btnPostStatus").click(function () {
    var post = $("#txtNewStatus").val();
    $.post('/Logic/postStory?text=' + post.toString() + '', null, function(result) {
        alert(result);
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: If you want to send actual POST data, you need `$.post('/Logic/postStory', { text: post }, function(result) { ... })`

Answer (score 1):

Encode them properly, via `encodeURIComponent`:

```
'/Logic/postStory?text=' + encodeURIComponent(post)
```

It's important to do that for **any** value you put in a URL query string. (In fact, keys should be done too, but `encodeURIComponent("text")` is `"text"` so you can get away with not doing it for that particular key, and any other that's just made up of letters and digits.)

Also note that both the `.toString()` on `post` and the `+ ''` are unnecessary.

---

Note that you're including the `text` parameter **in the URL** (e.g., like a GET parameter), not as POST data. If that's really what you mean to do, that's fine, but if you meant to include it in the POST data, you need to provide it as the second argument: `$.post('/Logic/postStory', {text: post}, ...)`. (And if you pass it that way, as an object, jQuery will handle doing the URI-encoding for you.)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `#` sign in a URL is interpreted as a so called [named anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800187/what-is-it-when-a-link-has-a-pound-sign-in-it). Try encoding the URL like this:

```
$.post('/Logic/postStory?text=' +  encodeURIComponent(post.toString()), ...
```

BTW, the `+ ''` is not necessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

`#` should be replaced with `%23`

Please check [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for more details.

You can encode request using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) or simply by replacing `#` with `%23` in your code.

I would suggest to encode whole URL.